# Is there any industry using NRTK technology for measuring distance to the hole?

Tags: equipment, golf, technology

We're investigating a new idea: 'Distance measuring instrument for golf using network real-time kinematic (NRTK) for high-accuracy'.

Does anyone knows if there is any industry using this technology for golf?